# PrimeNG charts legend right and left position issue

Tags: angular, chart.js, primeng

I have been using PrimeNG doughnut chart. The problem is that when I am making legend position left or right, it throws an error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined" but works fine for top or bottom.

```
  this.options = {
      responsive: false,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend:{
        position: 'right'
      }
  };


errors.ts:42 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
at i.draw (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
at t.Controller.<anonymous> (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
at Object.a.each (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
at t.Controller.draw (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
at i.a.render (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
at Object.startDigest (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
at Chart.bundle.min.js:13
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:424)
at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.ts:254)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
```

Comment: Which version of Chart.js do you use ? It should be at least 2.1.5 according to this [issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3652).

Comment: I am using primeng version 4.3.0

Comment: I am using primeng charts which is using charts.js of version 2.7.1

Comment: got my result.thnx for the response

Comment: What have you done ? It could help anyone else. :)

Comment: sorry i was using 2.1.3 chart.js. just upgraded to 2.5.1